# Make Image overlay clickable to link to another page

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, overlay, clickable

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e0u4sow1/

I want to use the following code for an image to link to another page. Right now if I make it a link it doesn't work. I read somewhere I need to add

```
pointer-events: none;
```

somewhere in the code. It tried, but it either doesn't work or it works but removes the overlay.

HTML:

```
<h1>MR Cube</h1>
<div class="media"></div>
<div class="media"><a href="http://www.google.nl/"><img alt="" class="media__image" src="http://www.webwinkelsucces.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1112625-les-outils-de-test-et-d-integration-continue-open-source.jpg" /></a>
<div class="media__body">
<h1>Lees meer</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.media {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.media__image { display: block; }

.media__body {
  background: rgba(41, 128, 185, 0.7);
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 3.75em 3em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.media__body:hover { opacity: 1; }

.media__body:after,
.media__body:before {
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  bottom: 1em;
  content: '';
  left: 1em;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
  -webkit-transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
  transition: 0.6s 0.2s;
}

.media__body:before {
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
  left: 2em;
  right: 2em;
}

.media__body:after {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  bottom: 2em;
  top: 2em;
}

.media__body:hover:after,
.media__body:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}

.media__body h2 { margin-top: 0; }

.media__body p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
```

Comment: you should use `jsfiddle` so we can test your code

Comment: Please consider upvoting answers in case they are helpful to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move `.media__body` inside `a`

```
<a href="http://www.google.nl/">
    <img alt="" class="media__image" src="http://www.webwinkelsucces.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1112625-les-outils-de-test-et-d-integration-continue-open-source.jpg" />
    <div class="media__body">
        <h1>Lees meer</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Venugopal/e0u4sow1/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-container{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
  
.image-container img {
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto;
  display: block; /* added this */
  
}

.image-container a {
  position:absolute;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:2;
  
}

.image-container .image-overlay{
  opacity:0;
  position:absolute;
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(141, 178, 215, 0.77);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:40px;
  line-height: 200px;  /* added this */

  
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  z-index:1;
}

.image-container:hover .image-overlay{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="image-container">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <div class="image-overlay">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/350x350">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although JQuery has not been tagged, this is what you could have done using it:

```
$(".media__body").click(function(){
    window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
});
```

[Here is a **Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGZboB)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, just wrap all tags used for image with `<a>` tag

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e0u4sow1/2/)**

```
<h1>MR Cube</h1>
<a href="www.google.com" >
<div class="media"></div>
<div class="media"><img alt="" class="media__image" src="http://www.webwinkelsucces.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/1112625-les-outils-de-test-et-d-integration-continue-open-source.jpg" />
<div class="media__body">
<h1>Lees meer</h1>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```